# Changing theme dynamically using PHP

Tags: php

I am doing a project in which client is demanding to add an option of theme changer. Multiple themes will be given (i will make those one) and from drop down user can select the theme which he/she like. So in this way each user may have same or different layouts of this profile. I want to know the best method how to do a theme changer functionality.

One idea in my mind is that i store all the html code inside the database of each themes as a new record and will populate in a drop down with following names:

```
1- Theme 1
2- Theme 2 and so on.
```

Is there any good and better idea to implement this functionality. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing Template Code for your themes in a database might not be a good practice, since you may be changing these from time to time. Especially during development.

You may want to have your template files structured in different locations:

- Themes/

  - Theme1/
  - Theme2/

What you want to save your database / or even just in configuration is the path for each theme. Then have some convention to load a theme and have it so both themes support that convention, but that really depends on your application here.

Have the selected theme value stored somewhere in either frontend or backend (localstorage, cookie, session,.... user attribute in your users table ...) and have your application use that value to determine the theme(-path) to use.
In your frontend, have your select connected to an action that creates/changes that saved value.

If you really like to have that template code in your database, you can always go on import your theme to your DB for your production and staging environments. Or have parts of it compiled in either files or database.